# Typescript - passing a callback to an @injectible service that does subscribe

Tags: angular, typescript

I have an `@Injectable` service in Angular2 that does this:

```
startAllSensors() {
  this.accSub = this.deviceMotion.watchAcceleration({ frequency: this.freq }).subscribe((acceleration: DeviceMotionAccelerationData) => {
    doMyFancyShmancyFoo();
  });

  // listen to gyro data
  this.gyrSub = this.gyroscope.watch({ frequency: this.freq }).subscribe((gyroscope: GyroscopeOrientation) => {
    doMyFancyShmancyFoo();
  });
}
```

I'd like the `doMyFancyShmancyFoo()` to be a parameter that I can pass to `startAllSensors` from my calling component, which means I want to do something like:

**calling.ts**

```
this.sensors.startAllSensors(accCallback, gyroCallback);
accCallback (data) { // will be called each time the injectable service has data to report }
gyroCallback (data) { // will be called each time the injectable service has data to report }
```

I understand I can use `@Input` and `@Output` between components, but not sure how to apply that when its a service.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Typescript methods within services can accept functions as parameters:

```
  startAllSensors(accCallback: Function, gyroCallback: Function) {
      this.accSub = this.deviceMotion.watchAcceleration({ frequency: this.freq })
          .subscribe((acceleration: DeviceMotionAccelerationData) => {
              accCallback();
          });
      this.gyrSub = this.gyroscope.watch({ frequency: this.freq })
          .subscribe((gyroscope: GyroscopeOrientation) => {
              gyroCallback();
          });
  }
```

Then the following call from your component should work:

```
this.sensors.startAllSensors(accCallback, gyroCallback);
```